# Generated links and HTML tag fields in tables for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have many tables in my rails application. I use for administrate them active_admin. But I get 2 problems and I doesn't know how solve them.

The first one is link problem. I want to every row generate link to current page. For example, in table `articles` I want add link to this page like `/articles/44`? (where 44 is `id` field in this table.)

The second problem is add images or something else in fields on this tables. On `boolean` fields I see `true` and `false` results, but how I can change this text to some images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look a the documentation for tables: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

it then looks like this:

```
  index do
    column "Link to Article" do |article|
      link_to article.title, article_path(article)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I make some other html? Or maybe I can add some styles or class which this tag can see them? For example make some empty link  with `40x40` pixel width and some background image.